# How do you output a view file as an ajax response in Java?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am a PHP developer but am transitioning to Java. (very new to Java at this point)

Is there a way to make an ajax call to a Servlet, and respond with the output of a separate .jsp file (as opposed to html or json created directly in the Servlet)?

Here is an example of what is common practice w/ Zend Framework, which is what I would like to do with Java if possible:

```
public function myAjaxCallAction(){
    $this->view->someVar = 'whatever';
    $this->view->hello = 'world';
    $output = $this->view->render('someViewScript.phtml'); // the above vars are in this view
    echo $output;
}
```

Again very new to java, any advice pertaining to this type of situation would be much appreciated!

Comment: A JSP file is basically just a HTML template. You're not required to put the full block of `<html>...</html>` in a JSP. Just a part of it like `<div>...</div>` is also absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to load the .jsp that you want. Normally you will use a JSP fragment (.jspf). If you want to load its contents, you can do something like:

Your page:

```
... content ...
<div id="container"></div>
... content ...
```

Javascript of the page above (using jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $( "#container" ).load( "pathToYoutJsp/file.jsp", { someVar: "whatever", hello: "world" } );
});
```

The JSP that will be loaded will look something like:

```
... content ...
${param.someVar} foo foo foo ${param.hello}
... content ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If i get your question correctly then what you want to do is a simple AJAX request to a JSP file and get reaponse. Do it as follows:

In client Javascript:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlHttp.open( "GET","ajaxreq.jsp?query=John", false ); 
xmlHttp.send(); 
return xmlHttp.responseText;
//returns the response from server. here it is "Hello John"
```

In server ajaxreq.jsp :

```
<% 
..              //import required libraries and other application logic
out.print("Hello "+request.getParameter("query"));
..
%>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ajax without browser check? Scriptlet in a JSP?

Comment: @davidbuzatto not a perfect code. just giving some skeleton.. will add now.

Comment: You didn't understood what I said. I said that because your code have bad practices. You need to use Ajax through a library thta will do the browse check, unless you do it by yourself. Using scriplets is not a goot thing too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by using request.setAttribute before dispatch and then dispatch to your separate page

```
request.setAttribute("someVa", "whatever");

RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher; 

requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/thankYou.jsp");

requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

See the following link [redirect jsp from servlet RequestDispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962989/redirect-jsp-from-servlet-requestdispatcher)