# Creating elements and manipulating them with jQuery outside of the dom

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I tried looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813691/jquery-selecting-and-manipulating-html-elements-outside-the-dom) which has an almost identical title but despite trying the answer that appeared suitable, my code still isn't working.

I'm creating an element outside of the dom like this:

```
var e = $('<div class="alert"><div class="messageBox"><h1>'+type+'</h1><p class="message">'+message+'</p></div></div>');
```

On the next line, I'm attempting to manipulate it.

```
$('.alert',e).width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
```

As you can see, I tried to define the context for the selector (the suggestion I saw in the other post) but it isn't working. Can someone point out to me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.alert` div is already at the root of your `e` variable DOM contents, so no need to use context parameter (that will cause to **find** inside your `.alert` div for another `.alert` div, which won't find anything) so just do like this:

```
e.width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
```

If you were to assign some property to your `.messageBox` div, then it would work to use the context parameter like you did:

```
 //this will work as .messageBox is inside your root element(.alert)
 $('.messageBox',e).width(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's always something simple isn't it... I'll check the answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.alert',e)` is equivalent to `e.find('.alert')` which returns nothing because `e` is `.alert`

Just use:

```
e.width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
```