# Javascript location.href for java

Tags: java

There is something like location.href javascript but for java.
I need it in a jsp page.
I'm using javascript now, but will be better for me in a jsp page.
Tx.

Comment: Do you want to get the current url, or redirect to another url?

Comment: "Is there something like backpedal braking for my dishwasher?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `RequestDispatcher.forward()` to route the request from controller to the view, you can use in your servlet:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

or in JSP:

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
```

If you want the path of your file from inside the JSP:

```
${pageContext.request.servletPath}
```

If you are inside the servlet, you can try this way:

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();

String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

If you are somewhere else:

```
String port = ( Executions.getCurrent().getServerPort() == 80 ) ? "" : (":" + Executions.getCurrent().getServerPort());
url = Executions.getCurrent().getScheme() + "://" + Executions.getCurrent().getServerName() + port + Executions.getCurrent().getContextPath() +  Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getRequestPath();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the browser to navigate to a different location, use a redirect:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)

If you just want to know which page you are on (its path) then there are is:

```
request.getRequestURI()  -> /foo/bar?key=value
request.getRequestURL()  -> http://www.domain.de/foo/bar (without query)
request.getPathInfo()    -> /foo/bar (including /)
request.getQueryString() -> key=value (without ?)
```

But generally have a look here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: not redirect, i need to know what is mi url path, example "http://www.mipage/subdomine/mipage.jsp". i need to know "http://www.mipage/subdomine/"

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to use the RequestDispatcher. Have a look at [redirect jsp from servlet RequestDispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962989/redirect-jsp-from-servlet-requestdispatcher)