# JSP Not Found After SendRedirect

Tags: jsp, tomcat

My JSP's location is **src / webcontent / WEB-INF / jsp / sessionTimeout.jsp**.

It's not found after I do a sendRedirect as below, from a Filter. I've already tried these combinations:

```
((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/jsp/sessionTimeout.jsp");
((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("sessionTimeout.jsp");
((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("jsp/sessionTimeout.jsp");
((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath() +  "/jsp/sessionTimeout.jsp");
```

404 Error. Code:

```
public class SpringMVCControllerFilter implements Filter
{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException         
{
        if (session.isValid() && !session.isNew())
        {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else
        {             ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("jsp/sessionTimeout.jsp");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything under WEB-INF is inaccessible from the outside, on purpose. Put it anywhere you like except there if you want to access it from the browser.

JSPs are often put under WEB-INF because JSPs are views, and a request should always go to a controller that prepares the model and dispatches to a view.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear at first. Our structure is src/webcontent/WEB-INF/... , so I believe it should be found. I've edited the original post. I have a solution which works for some reason, while this one didn't, see my answer below.

Comment: Webcontent constitutes, in your source project, the root of the webapp. Your solution works because it dispatches (forwards) the current request to the JSP. A redirect is completely different from a forward: it asks the browser to send a new request to the JSP. And since it's inaccessible from the outside, it fails.

Comment: Then why do all the examples on this topic give sendRedirect("/page.jsp"), where everyone places their JSPs in the usual inaccessible WEB-INF location? I've seen thousands of examples with the sendRedirect, which would never work according to this.

Comment: I think you're overgeneralizing: many people (including me) put their JSPs in WEB-INF: all those people use MVC and thus NEVER access a JSP directly, because a request is supposed to first go through a controller, and then be forwarded to the JSP. many newbies tutorials send a redirect to a JSP. In those tutorials, the JSPs are not under WEB-INF (otherwise, the redirect would fail). If you think I'm wrong, show me a tutorial that redirect to a JSP stored under WEB-INF and that works.

Comment: Some quick examples: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/servlets/redirecting-from-servlet-jsp , http://stackoverflow.com/a/13622427/1005607 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/15826338/1005607 , https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194061-how-to-redirect-to-another-jsp-from-java . JSPs typically go under WEB-INF but no one mentions their sendRedirect examples won't work.

Comment: None of the links you posted show that their JSPs in under WEB-INF. JSPs don't typically go under WEB-INF. That's an incorrect assumption that you are making. People put them there when they don't want anybody to be able to access them from the outside. Because they're using MVC. And accessing views without going through a controller is plain wrong in an MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked for me:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/sessionTimeout.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

whereas this from the original post did not, none of the combinations below worked (nothing with sendRedirect):

```
((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/jsp/sessionTimeout.jsp");
((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("sessionTimeout.jsp");
((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("jsp/sessionTimeout.jsp");
```

I'll use the RequestDispatcher, but still not sure why the sendRedirect always failed to redirect to the JSP.